# Best way to store OOP logic in Android data storage using SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, oop

I'm having trouble with a specific subtopic of using an SQLite database for android storage.

SQLite seems like the most efficient method of storing data in my data-heavy application, however due to the custom object design I have set up I'm confused on how to implement it. For those interested it's a D&D app I'm just making in my free time.

I have a **Player**, that is a subclass of **Creature**, that stores **Armor, Item, Weapon,** and **Spell** objects within that Player. This Player also associates itself with multiple enumerations like **Classification** and **Race** with constants so the game can get traits from those enums about how the player should function. All of these classes and enumerations have data fields to store information. So *LOTS* of data.

I can't see how an SQLite database can gracefully keep track of this kind of relational information. If there is a way to link data between tables relatively easily I would prefer that, I really want to avoid doing serialization. I'm a programming student with limited experience in SQLite so I apologize if the answer is sitting in front of my face.

Comment: You could try and take a look at alternative db's like Realm or ObjectBox which will make your life a lot easier

Comment: Thank you so much! Realm looks like exactly what I was looking for. SQLite seemed a little too limited in scope for my project.

Comment: You need just a relationship 1-1, 1-n, n-n

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos when the data is being manipulated in Java, and I have the data stored in Objects, how does the database keep track of those relationships? For example, if I have a Container Object that stores an Item Object in my code, how do I keep those objects in-sync with their respective entries in SQLite? Or should I even be using Objects?

Comment: Ohh.. didnt noticed you wanted real time data